# Xlookup by last entry without overwriting previous entry

Tags: excel, vba, xlookup

i have a scanner register, using an in and out sheet for when the team member scans a scanner out with time stamp, then back in with time stamp. then the overview shows it all together.
my issue is when the a scanner gets scanned out then back in on AM shift, then PM shift scans the same scanner back out it will overwrite the previous entry.
[image: Scan Out]
[image: Scan In]
[image: Overview with desired results]

Now when i try scan out scanner 1 with a different name (someone on PM shift) it will add the line on the overview but it will pull the name from the original entry (Mark 1 instead of Mark 3)[image]

if i changed the search mode to look for the last entry first then the last entry overrides the previous ones[image]

How can i make it not override the previous entrys so i am able to scan scanner 1 out more then once per shift?

Comment: You will need vba.  formulas are live and will change as the values in the references change.